# Pass textarea value to server php

Tags: php

I'm trying to capture the value of a text area and pick you up php so that it kept on the server. The functionality that is what I do is to change texts and photos so pretend that these changes I have made are saved.

Where I can move friends.
Thank you very much for your time .

That's my last try:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
$salida = $_GET['textarea'];     
$archivo = fopen("prueba2.html", "w+");
fputs($archivo, $salida);
$contenido = file_get_contents($archivo);
fclose($abrir);
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the `html` form that is sending the data?

Comment: You can give the `<textarea></textarea>` tag a name like this: `<textarea name="Sample"></textarea>` And then you need to change the `$_GET['textarea']` to `$_GET['Sample']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$_GET` variable, but your `<form>` has method POST. You have to use `$_POST` variable instead.

Comment: Thank you but is not the solution...

Comment: Another bug I see is calling `isset($_GET['submit'])` but submit in your HTML has no name...

Comment: Thats rigth! Thank you I solve the problem with the name of submit... NooB! :( really thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thats it the html form really thank you

```
<form id="formulario" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <div>
            <h3>Haga "click" encima del contenido a modificar</h3>
        </div>
        <iframe id="probando" src="prueba2.html" scrolling="auto" height="700" width="800" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="probando"></iframe>
        <textarea name="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>

        <input id="botonGuardar" type="submit" value="Confirmar cambios"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `textarea` a name:

```
<form>
    <textarea name="myTextarea"></textarea>
    <!-- the rest of your form -->
</form>
```

And then in your php:

```
$salida = $_GET['myTextarea'];
```